# how to know Gps is off using FusedLocationProviderApi periodicaly

Tags: android, gps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am working in app where user location tracking all time and updated into server in background service, i update location to the server from onLocationChanged(Location location) @Override method. I want hit server when location is not changed also.  is there any @Override method who is call when Gps is off?Mean,i want to notify the server that user's gps is off.

Comment: if your app close than FusedLocationProviderApi running in background ??

Comment: yes,in all 10 secend interval

Comment: Hi Younas Bangash,any override method  or anything when user off the location?

Comment: Ok can you share the code please

Answer (score 0):

You can detect GPS on/off event/status with [GpsStatus.Listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html) and register it with the LocationManager.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.addGpsStatusListener(new android.location.GpsStatus.Listener()
{
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event)
    {
        switch(event)
        {
        case GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
            // do your tasks
            break;
        case GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
            // do your tasks
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks,for you contribution.but i want when gps off then fuesed location notify and then notify the server.

Comment: no override method available to detect the GPS is off. You try trick, onConnectionSuspended and onConnectionfailed and check your GPS is off then notify  to the  server. I think better to add GPS listener

Comment: thank you,but when called  onConnectionSuspended and onConnectionfailed ?because when i off the Gps then it is not called..